# How to dismiss DialogFragment from AsyncTask, when the home button is pressed and the device is resumed with changed rotation

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, dialogfragment

I have an `AsyncTask` which dismisses the `DialogFragment`. I am facing a problem when the `AsyncTask` tries to dismiss the dialog after pressing the home button. `dismissAllowingStateloss()` helps to this case, but one issue still remains. When I press home button and then rotate, the `AsyncTask` tries to dismiss the activity, but as the orientation is changed, the activity calls `onDestroy()` and recreates the stuff. As a result the `DialogFragment` is on the screen again. setRetainInstance is set to true for the `DialogFragment`. The normal `dismiss()` raises `IllegalStateException` by saying do not call after `onSavedInstance()`.

Any idea how to fix this by keeping the `DialogFragment` independent from the `Activity`? I mean without putting tracking variables in the `Activity`. I do not want to do this, because I do not want to write that stuff for each `Activity` where I would use this dialog.

Comment: Hard to say without code, but generally you can use FragmentManager to remove DialogFragment.

Comment: How can I do that, when after the rotation Activity is destroyed a new one is recreated?

Comment: You can differentiate a new Activity and restored Activity by savedInstanceState.